# How to auto-complete/suggest places (with address) on my website like on Google maps?

Tags: api, google-maps, autocomplete, maps

I am working a Yelp-like project that associates reviews to places. Yet, we don't have any database of places and we'd like to leverage a third-party api.
We'd like to start with a auto-complete search box like on Google Maps. For example, the user enters "tamar" and it suggests "Tamarine Restaurant, Palo Alto, CA, United States".
1) is it possible? what third party api would you use? Is Google maps the best?

Once the results are returned, the user selects one place and will leave a review.
2) how would you associate that review to that specific place in the DB? My concern is if later on we change api provider, that we can still associate our reviews to the new api places.

Thank you SO MUCH! Any suggestion would help.
Fab

Answer (score 1):

this will generate autocomplete also get the latitutde and longitutde in 2 textbox for storage on your DB if need.initially center is set statically    ..hope this is what you want

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var geocoder;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  function initialize() {
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: pyrmont,
   zoom: 15
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  var options = {
  bounds: pyrmont,
 //types: ['establishment']  dont mention it we need to get both bussiness andaddress
  };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#find").click(function(){

   var address = document.getElementById("searchTextField").value;
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var test = results[0].geometry.location;
    var latlang=String(test);
    latlang = latlang.substring(0, latlang.length-1);
    latlang= latlang.substr(1);
    var latlan = latlang.split(",");
    var lat = latlan[0];
    var lon = latlan[1];
    $("#latitude").val(lat);
            $("#longitude").val(lon);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
       alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
     }
   }); 
 });
});

</script>
```

```
  <body onload="initialize();">
 <label> Type address</label>
<input type="text" id="searchTextField" style="width:500px;" />
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
<input type="text" id="latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="longitude"/>
<input type="button" id="find"  value="Find"/>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an API at http://compass.webservius.com that can help. You can search a database of millions of businesses in the US (e.g. by a name prefix like in your example, by zip code, by latitude/longitude bounding box, etc) and get back results (such as business name, address, type, etc) in XML or JSON format.

For the second part of your question, it is tough because there is no "universal ID" for a business, but usually a combination of normalized postal address + business name will work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

HTML Form Input

```
<input id="locationName" name="locationName" type="text">
```

JavaScript

```
 function init() {
        var input = document.getElementById('locationName');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```